# Is a data point significantly larger than a certain distribution average?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a simulated distribution with mean 12.53% and standard deviation 11.83%. The sample size is big enough (10,000) to assume it is a Normal distribution.

How do I properly test if the value "26.05%" is significantly larger than the mean 12.53%? 
Can anyone please help me to write the null hypothesis, as well as the test, or just give me any reference that I'm not being able to find (or most probably to recognize) on the web?

Comment: A large sample size does not mean you can assume a Normal distribution. Your data seem to be % ages. If they have a lower limit of 0 (as % often do) then they are not normally distributed.

Comment: @PeterFlom, no, they don't have lower limits. They are profits, so might be both negative and positive (they are in the sample). But what I'd like to test is if a certain profit belongs to this distribution: it is for a software, so even if in this case it's clear that 26.05% is much larger than 12.53%, I'd like to write the test to be computed every time not depending on the value.

Comment: It sounds like you might want to look at material on outliers (lots of questions here on that topic - it's a complex one).

Comment: The answer *strongly* depends on how the value of 26.05% was obtained. Is it a new value? Is it one of the values in the simulated distribution, such as its maximum? Is it some predetermined *constant* independent of the simulation? Is it the average, or max, or min of some other random values?

Comment: @whuber It is some predetermined value independent of the simulation.

Answer (score -1):

One fairly simple way is to create a predictor series (x) and place '0' in it except for the point where the specific value is to be challenged place a "1". Estimate a regression model (OLS) between the y values (profit) and the x series. The t value for the predictor series will test the hypothesis that the challenged value is significantly different from the mean profit (mean of y excluding the challenged value).It is clear that if you select a value that is close to the overall mean the t ratio will be approximately zero suggesting that the null hypothesis should be accepted.

Comment: Since the dataset in the question has no intrinsic order--it's a "distribution," not a series--it seems your prescription is entirely arbitrary. How could it be applied in a consistent and effective way?

Comment: There is no need for order. If the data point in question is observation number nnn then set the nnnth point in x to be a "1"

Comment: *There are no observation numbers!* Any reasonable solution must be invariant under permutations of the observations, because they are exchangeable.  Regression is meaningless.

Comment: The list of values is from 1 to n.There is no order to this list . Examining the list we might find the nnnth value is 26.05 . Simply place a "1" in the nnnth position ( 0 elsewhere) of the x variable. Estimate an OLS model; y and the x variable . The regression coefficient for x represents the impact of the x variable over all pairs of observations. Since the only x that is non-zero is the nnnth value of x,this becomes the lift .(deviation from the intercept) due to x.Now if the "26.05" happens to be the mmmth observation simply place the "1" at the mmth position in x and get the same answer.

Comment: OK, I see what you are doing. I was baffled before because it is a strange way to compute a z-score! Moreover, the z-score alone does not address the problem for a multitude of reasons: the distribution could be non-normal (as @Peter points out) and there could be multiple outliers which inordinately influence the mean and the variance. However, based on the OP's earlier question I suspect that none of this is relevant. It seems likely he just wants to know how to find a quantile of an empirical distribution of data from a simulation--but we need to wait for his clarification to find out.

Answer (score -1):

@huber has questioned ny answer and I would like to address this. I simulated 300 values from a N(10,1) distribution .[image] . The basic statistics for this simulated set is

THE AVERAGE IS =                 9.961
 THE MEDIAN  IS =               11.119
 THE STD DEV IS =                1.023
 THE MINIMUM IS =                6.915
 THE MAXIMUM IS =               12.561
 THE # OF OBS   =              300

The 131'st value of this set is 11.96 with a companion x value of 1.0 ( all other values of x are 0.0) .I run an OLS model for the 300 observations and obtain:

[image]

[image]

The full regression results are :
[image]

Notice the "t value" for the estimated regression coefficient is 1.97 which is precisely what you would expect from ( 11.96-9.961)/1.023 .

This ( at last in my opinion ) is what the OP requested .

It is also clear that in this case ( independent readings / constant error variance) he could have just as easily used

[(MEAN-VALUE)]/STD DEVIATION to obtain the same result.

Comment: This seems to have *nothing* to do with the question! It clearly is not a regression question (there isn't even a variable to regress against), but you do regression; it asks to compare a mean to a "predetermined value independent of the simulation" (as explained in comments); and your simulated data are not at all like the data described in the question, either in quantity, mean, or standard deviation.